# Which approach for a form view conditionally showing sets of fields?

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift

I am working on an inventory control application that deals with a few different classes of items. The detail views for each class of item share a mostly the same items on the layout:

- Item Name
- Photo
- Description
- Qty in stock

In addition to the basics, different types of items will need to show additional information, like serialized-children or required sub-items etc... In an effort to reduce the number of different layouts I was considering two options:

---

### Option 1:

A tableview with each of these layout items (i.e.: item name, photo etc...) as a cell. Depending on the type of item only the relevant cells would be displayed and populated with data.

As can be seen in the attached screenshot of the FileMaker solution which I am trying to replicate, the fields are stacked vertically, so visually a tableview would work.

[image: stackedUI]

### Option 2:

Create a single view in Storyboard containing all of the possible fields. When a record is loaded into a view, only the relevant fields would be shown and then slide up to fill in space left by the hidden fields.

---

Being a newcomer to UI, I am asking for answers to contain the pros and cons of each approach and also encourage other reasonably simple alternative approaches that would achieve the same end-result. Do note that this project is written in Swift and I have no Objective-C experience so any examples are preferably in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are organizing data in this fashion the best approach is Option 1 using a table view. The biggest advantage is the `scrollToRowAtIndex` function which makes it easy to scroll to a specific text field when it becomes first responder. I'm not sure if you're manipulating data or just displaying it, but this is very helpful:

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

This option also has the advantage of using reusable cells for similar input types, so you only have to create one prototype cell . In addition, if one of your cells has more content, it is easy to resize it to the size of that content.

You stated " When a record is loaded into a view, only the relevant fields would be shown and then slide up to fill in space left by the hidden fields" but this can be applied to a table view as well.